# how to get fragment object from context

Tags: android, android-fragments, searchview, android-context

Is it possible to get the fragment object from the context object?  I am basically trying to access the fragment object from a SearchView class that i extended. Since context is the only object passed to the SearchView constructor, i was hoping to somehow get a reference to the fragment from it.

I know that we can get it from within an activity by using `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.xxx)`. But `getSupportFragmentManager()` is available only in a `FragmentActivity` class. Is there someway to access the fragment from another class?

Comment: How did you add the fragment to the FragmentManager if you do not have a reference to the FragmentActivity?

Comment: The `Context` reference is the `Activity`(so you can cast it and use it) unless you used something like `getApplicationContext()` when creating the view.

Comment: In my `FragmentActivity`, i call `setContentView(R.layout.fragmentlayout)`. `fragmentLayout` has a `<fragment>` element, so that's how the fragment gets started. What i want now is to get the instance of the running fragment in a class gets the context through it's constructor.

Comment: So why cant you call getSupportFragmentManager? You have a FragmentActivity that you are working in. Fragments are tied to the FragmentManager. Each FragmentManager is tied to its Activity.

If you do not have a FragmentActivity to work from, you cannot add a Fragment to the its FragmentManager.

Comment: @Kuffs yes i can get the fragment from the FragmentActivity, but what i want to do is to get a reference to the fragment from another class, that is instantiated in the fragment. I do not want to add the fragment..just get a reference.

Comment: @Luksprog you are right. Simply casting the context to the FragmentActivity worked!

Comment: can i know why the question got down voted so i can avoid it next time?

Comment: @Luksprog If you could post your comment as an answer, i can accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't mess with the normal way a `View` is built then the `Context` reference that you receive in the constructor of a `View` is the `Activity`(a `Context`) where the `View` is being used. So, you have the option of casting that `Context` to an `Activity` reference and from there you can use one of the various ways to access the desired `Fragment`.